# prevent uploading of large and unsupported files in image upload form

Tags: php, image, upload

i have a php form with an image upload option as follows

```
 <input type="hidden" name="old_picture" value="<?php if (!empty($old_picture)) echo        $old_picture; ?>" />
  <label for="new_picture">Picture:</label>
  <input type="file" id="new_picture" name="new_picture" />
```

and php script something like

```
if (!empty($new_picture)) {
  if ((($new_picture_type == 'image/gif') || ($new_picture_type == 'image/jpeg') || ($new_picture_type == 'image/pjpeg') ||
    ($new_picture_type == 'image/png')) && ($new_picture_size > 0) && ($new_picture_size <= MM_MAXFILESIZE) &&
    ($new_picture_width <= MM_MAXIMGWIDTH) && ($new_picture_height <= MM_MAXIMGHEIGHT)) {
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == 0) {
      // Move the file to the target upload folder
      $target = MM_UPLOADPATH . basename($new_picture);
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_picture']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        // The new picture file move was successful, now make sure any old picture is deleted
        if (!empty($old_picture) && ($old_picture != $new_picture)) {
          @unlink(MM_UPLOADPATH . $old_picture);
        }
      }
      else {
        // The new picture file move failed, so delete the temporary file and set the error flag
        @unlink($_FILES['new_picture']['tmp_name']);
        $error = true;
        echo '<p class="error">Sorry, there was a problem uploading your picture.</p>';
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    // The new picture file is not valid, so delete the temporary file and set the error flag
    @unlink($_FILES['new_picture']['tmp_name']);
    $error = true;
    echo '<p class="error">Your picture must be a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image file no greater than ' . (MM_MAXFILESIZE / 1024) .
      ' KB and ' . MM_MAXIMGWIDTH . 'x' . MM_MAXIMGHEIGHT . ' pixels in size.</p>';
  }
}
```

every thing works fine but problem occurs when as a test i tried to upload a .zip file the image was not loaded but it flushed my database. all the entries for that user were deleted.

now i want a some suggessions about how to prevent this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, there is not much you can do that you can actually rely on. But it can help prevent accidental problems.

Add this attribute to the file upload control to limit file types: `accept="image/gif, image/jpeg"`

Your validation needs to happen on server side if you want to be sure about what you are getting.

Check `$_FILES['uploadctl']['size']` for the size of the file and see if it exceeds your limits.

You can force php to limit what size file uploads it accepts by setting `upload_max_filesize` in php.ini. Default for this is pretty low.

You cant really trust that the extension of an uploaded file is actually correct. Just because it says `.jpg` doesn't mean it really is. If all you are accepting is images, you should be able to verify the mimetype with `getimagesize()`. If you are accepting a larger range of files, check the file with Fileinfo.

If the entries in the database were deleted, you probably have a logic problem in code that you are not showing here.